# Como mantener una variable global en nodejs

Tags: nodejs, reactjs

**Problema** : He creado un login con nodejs y usando una API rest de django, estoy intentando guardar el nick de usuario en una variable global para así que me sea más fácil usarla en alguna otra funcionalidad, la cosa es que creando la variable global `usuarioLogeado` cada vez que cambio de componente se pierde esta y su valor vuelve a `null`, es decir solo se mantiene como el valor del formulario del login en la componente de `login.js` cuando cambio a otra se vuelve a `null`

## Parte de código del `Login.js`

```
global.usuarioLogeado = require('./user');

async function loginUser(credenciales) {
  const url =
    "http://localhost:8000/api/Usuarios/?search=" + credenciales.usuario;
  var response = await axios.get(url);
  var data = response.data;

  if (data.length > 0) {
    data.forEach((element) => {
      if (element.nombre === credenciales.usuario) {
        if (element.password === credenciales.password) {
          global.usuarioLogeado = credenciales.usuario;
          console.log(global.usuarioLogeado)
          window.location.replace("/");
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

## `User.js`

```
var usuarioLogeado = null;

module.exports = usuarioLogeado;
```

## `App.js`

```
function App() {
  console.log(global.usuarioLogeado);
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Nav />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/Login" exact component={Login} />
          <Route path="/Register" exact component={Register} />
          <Route path="/Noticias" exact component={Noticias} />
          <Route path="/Estadisticas" exact component={Estadisticas} />
          <Route path="/CompraVenta" exact component={CompraVenta} />
          <Route path="/Plantilla" exact component={Plantilla} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Necesitas manejar el estado con un hook, específicamente `setState`, de lo contrario React no va a poder relacionar tu variable global con el ciclo de vida del componente. Y por lo tanto los cambios a dicha variable son "invisibles" para React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que lo que buscas es **mantener una variable global** en el `Front end`.

Una posible solución es usando [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

El siguiente ejemplo es mínimo, pero suficiente para observar el comportamiento de `React context` y puedas continuar con el diseño de tu sistema `login`.

Correlo en página completa, hay unos warnings que ocultan el botón de `login`:

```js
const Router = window.ReactRouterDOM.HashRouter;
const Route =  window.ReactRouterDOM.Route;
const Link =  window.ReactRouterDOM.Link;
const Switch =  window.ReactRouterDOM.Switch;

/*
Se crean los contextos
*/
const userContext = React.createContext(null);
const setUserContext = React.createContext(null);


function App(){
  //Se crea un estado al inicio de la app
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState({});
  
  return(
    <div>
        <Router>
            {/*Se envuelven las rutas en los contextos
        y se pasan los valores del estado user*/}
           <userContext.Provider value={user}>
           <setUserContext.Provider value={setUser}>
        
               <Link to="/home">- Home - </Link>
               <Link to="/Login">Login - </Link>
               <Link to="/Register">Register - </Link>
               <Link to="/Noticias">Noticias -</Link>

          <Switch>
        
              <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
              <Route path="/home" exact component={Home} />
              <Route path="/Login" exact component={Login} />
              <Route path="/Register" exact component={Register} />
              <Route path="/Noticias" exact component={Noticias} />
          </Switch>
          </setUserContext.Provider>
          </userContext.Provider>
       </Router>
    </div>
  );
};

function Home(){
  //podemos acceder al contexto en cualquier componente hijo
  //y profundidad n
  const userInfo = React.useContext(userContext);
  
  const userIsLoged = <div>{(Object.keys(userInfo).length) ? userInfo.first +" "+ userInfo.last  : null}</div>;
  return (
      <div>{userIsLoged}
         <h3>Estas en Home</h3>
      </div>
  );
}

function Login(){
  //se usan los contextos user y setUser
  const userInfo = React.useContext(userContext);
  const setUserInfo = React.useContext(setUserContext);
  const userIsLoged = <div>{(Object.keys(userInfo).length) ? userInfo.first +" "+ userInfo.last  : null}</div>;
  
  function loginAPI(){
      fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
          const user = data.results[0].name;
          setUserInfo(user);
       });
  }
  
  return (
      <div>{userIsLoged}
      <h3>Estas en Login</h3>
         <h3><button onClick={loginAPI}>Login!</button></h3>
      </div>
  );
}

function Register(){
    return <h3>Estas en register</h3>
}

function Noticias(){
  //podemos acceder al contexto en cualquier componente hijo
  //y profundidad n
  const userInfo = React.useContext(userContext);
  const userIsLoged = <div>{(Object.keys(userInfo).length) ? userInfo.first +" "+ userInfo.last  : null}</div>;
  return (
      <div>{userIsLoged}
         <h3>Estas en Noticias</h3>
      </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/react-router@5.0.0/umd/react-router.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@5.0.0/umd/react-router-dom.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js'></script>
    
<div id="root"></div>
```

#### Notas de campo

> ¿Porque usar `context`, si puedo solo pasar la variable `user` y la función `setUser` como `props`?

Consideremos que el diseño puede necesitar nested components, con `context` se puede llamar a `user` y `setUser` en profundidad `n`, sin necesidad de pasarlos como `props` entre componentes (Props drilling).

El siguiente paso pude ser encapsular el contexto en un modulo por separado e importarlo el los componentes que lo necesiten.

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

En react lo más correcto es usar un `useContext` . Pero con un `customHook` es suficiente. Solo que debes llamarlo que cada `path` para asegurarte si sigue "logueado" o no.

Como el response es asíncrono, el primer dato que recibe el componente es `null`. Sin un estado , ese valor se va a mantener aunque llegue luego el valor correcto. Así que usa un `useState` y luego cuando escale el programa pásalo a un `customHook` y si lo completas pásalo a un `useContext`.